# Is the Linux system in one runlevel after bootup or does it go from one runlevel to another during the process of bootup?

Tags: boot, runlevel

Is the Linux system in one runlevel after bootup or does it go from one runlevel to another during the process of bootup?

This means that when we power on the cpu, and the default run level mentioned in the system file is "multiuser with GUI", does this mean that while booting up no other runlevel will be executed, or does it mean that first runlevel 1 will be executed, then 2, then 3, and finally runlevel 5 which is "multiuser with GUI"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### SySVInit

Referring to older Linux systems that still used SySVInit and the runlevel process. The correct understanding would be that it only goes to the one runlevel. The one runlevel has particular services associated with it, and only those services would be started. To clarify though, a service can be associated with multiple runlevels. So if a service is set to start with runlevel 3 and 5. Either runlevel can start that service. However, if a service is only associated with runlevel 3, going to runlevel 5 will not start that service.

#### Upstart

Upstart also still used and acknowledge runlevels but in a more robust way than SysVInit. The method of handling runlevels was the same as SySVInit though.

#### Systemd

Systemd does not use runlevels but rather targets. Targets utilize starting services in parallel and have other nifty features making it much better and faster than the previous two "init" based systems. Systemd however, still has the same principle in the area to which you are asking. If I were to go to "runlevel" or target "graphical", it would not go through "multi-user" or any other target before-hand.